# Symfony кастомизация locale

Tags: php, symfony

Тестирую с симфони, пытаюсь сделать проект с геотергетингом. Для Этого я решил использовать встроенный в симфони locale, но переделать его под города. Прикрутил определение и запись города, все хорошо, но столкнулся с проблемой так называемого whiteList для городов. Дело в том что мне не нужно чтобы в маршрут попадали "левые url". Сделал так:

```
#routes.yaml

main_locale:
   path: /{_locale}
   controller: App\Controller\Web\MainController::index
   requirements:
      _locale: '%app.locales%'
```

Затем в параметрах указал:

```
locales.yaml

parameters:
  app.locales: moscow|saratov|sochi
```

Все работает хорошо, однако это удобно в случае, когда городов немного, а если их 1000, прописывать каждый не хочется, удобнее тянуть из базы или из метода. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать в таком случае?

Comment: Сделать CompilerPass, который стянет из БД данные и установит значение параметра.

Comment: Спасибо ваш комментарий очень помог!

Comment: @u_mulder, столкнулся с проблемой при выполнении моего бандла, возникает ошибка, так как я пытаюсь обратиться к бд через CompilerPass во время компиляции, когда доступа к службе еще нет. Не могу найти правильное решение. Я использую PassConfig::TYPE_AFTER_REMOVING в своем бандле, в CompilerPass пытаюсь вызвать $container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')->getRepository. Я пробовал вызывать $container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')->getConnection() - который показал мне дефолтные значения базы данных https://prnt.sc/1uxs9wk, при этом база лежит в соседнем контейнере

Comment: Создайте кастомный router loader тогда.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html

правда надо посмотреть на предмет закинуть роут в кеш ибо при каждом запросе дергать в базу данных - так себе история.

Comment: А порядок загрузки бандлов какой? По идее сначала должен грузиться бандл с доктриной и т.д. И только потом твой.

Comment: Да, порядок я выставил тоже верный, но все равно ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил следующим образом: Добавил проход компилятора "CompilerPass" в котором добавил определение параметра, добавил собственный бандл, подключил его. Основная ошибка с которой я столкнулся, это подключение к базе в CompilerPass, по какой-то причине doctrine.dbal.url - не работал, пришлось вручную в doctrine.yaml вписывать подключение к базе, что не очень хорошо, но работает. Причину этой ошибки я не совсем понимаю, так что если есть решение лучше, просьба подсказать в комментариях.